# Second maximum value using OVER

Tags: max, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm trying to compare one source of demand against the top two different highest demand sources such that I can do some operations in SQL.

Here is what I have for the maximum and the specific demand, but I can't figure out how to find the second max. I've seen `max(x) where x <> max(x)`, but I am not sure how to work that into windows functions.

select row_id_str, Max_NR, Max_R

```
from(
    select row_id_str,
        MAX(NR_close) OVER (PARTITION BY row_id_str) as Max_NR,
        MAX(R_close) OVER (PARTITION BY row_id_str) as Max_R
    from(
        SELECT  row_id_str, demand, close,
        sum(if(demand = 'root', close, 0)) as R_close,
        sum(if(demand != 'root', close, 0)) as NR_close
        FROM [scratch] group by 1,2,3
        order by row_id_str, close desc)
    group by row_id_str, NR_close, R_close)
group by 1,2,3
```

#### Solution

```
select row_id_str, Max_NR, Max_R, Sum(if(RN=2, NR_close, 0)) as Second_Max
from(
    select row_id_str,  NR_close,
    MAX(NR_close) OVER (PARTITION BY row_id_str) as Max_NR,
    MAX(R_close) OVER (PARTITION BY row_id_str) as Max_R,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by row_id_str order by NR_close desc) as RN
    from(
        SELECT  row_id_str, demand_rtb_name, close, sum(if(demand_rtb_name = 'rubicon', close, 0)) as R_close, sum(if(demand_rtb_name != 'rubicon', close, 0)) as NR_close
        FROM [scratch.oRubicon1_3] group by 1,2,3
        order by row_id_str, close desc)
    group by row_id_str, close, NR_close, R_close)
group by 1,2,3,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX` in combination with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Wrap a new select around it, and select a particular row with `WHERE RowNumber = 2`

```
SELECT 
    tMax.row_id_str,
    tMax.MyMax,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(tMax.MyMax)) AS RowNumber
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t.row_id_str, 
        MAX(t.NR_close)
    FROM
        table AS t
    GROUP BY
        t.row_id_str
    ) AS tMax
```

Comment: So I added ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by row_id_str order by NR_close desc) as RN to the second select along with NR_close and then on the top select I added Sum(if(RN=2, NR_close, 0)) as Second_Max. Thanks